# Images can not be deleted - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, recycle-bin

why can pictures still be loaded into sprites, when they were deleted?

> self.sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"imageName"];

i was wondering that the code still works although i moved it to the trash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image was only deleted from the Xcode project. It still exists in the build and on the device (or simulator).

To fix this you need to delete the app from the device/simulator, then do a clean build in Xcode.